# Lambda type inference infers an exception type not thrown by the lambda

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8, type-inference

The code

```
class TestException extends Exception {

}

interface Task<E extends Exception> {
    void call() throws E;
}

public class TaskPerformer {

    /** performs a task in the proper context, rethrowing any exceptions the task declares */
    private <E extends Exception> void perform(Task<E> task) throws E {
        beforeTask();
        try {
            task.call();
        } finally {
            afterTask();
        }
    }

    private void afterTask() {
        // implementation elided (does not matter)
    }

    private void beforeTask() {
        // implementation elided (does not matter)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TaskPerformer().perform(() -> {       // compilation error
            try {
                throw new TestException();
            } catch (TestException e) {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

is rejected by the eclipse compiler with the error

> Unhandled exception type TestException

at the first line of main, even though the lambda expression handles this exception (right?).

Is this a compiler bug, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in `Eclipse`. The jdk compiles your code without problems.

Comment: @Holger, same result here with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_31. meriton, have you checked open bugs in Eclipse?

Comment: I thought the bound of `E` in `perform` would be `Exception`, but it's inferred to `RuntimeException` when no checked exception is thrown from the lambda. Didn't see that the error said `TestException`.

Comment: FWIW IntelliJ doesn't exhibit this problem

Comment: @beresfordt: afaik, IntelliJ uses `javac` so it should exhibit the same behavior. Only `Eclipse` has it’s own compiler.

Comment: You do still get the occasional thing highlighted as a compilation error in IntelliJ's editor window that actually compiles without issue though

Answer (score 4):

There had been tons of bugs in recent releases of Eclipse (and also javac, IntelliJ, etc.) with respect to lambda expressions and type inference. Just today, I've registered [460511](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460511), [460515](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460515), and [460517](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460517). For instance, there had been quite a few fixes around the combination of lambda expressions and exception types in this issue alone:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429430

I don't have the issue you're experiencing in Eclipse 4.5.0 M5 (nor with javac build 1.8.0_40-ea-b21), so I'm taking a bet that this is a bug, and it has been fixed.

As a general rule of thumb, if you're using Java 8 with Eclipse, do upgrade to the latest Mars (4.5.0) milestone. Always. It'll save you dozens of headaches.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Indeed, many comments on this issue refer to the need to perform a full flow analysis to determine the exceptions a lambda can throw. Such an analysis would indeed discover that my lambda does not throw TestException, causing RuntimeException to be inferred. Glad to hear that the bug is fixed in newer versions, we'll look into upgrading.